# MySQL not writing to error log + wrong owner of file

Tags: mysql

I have a problem running MySQL 8 where the error logs are not being written. The contents of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` includes:

```
[mysqld]

log_error_verbosity=2
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log          

slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time=5
slow_query_log=1

general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/general.log
general_log=1
```

With this configuration, both the `slow.log` and the `general.log` files are written correctly. The owner of these files is `mysql:adm`.

However, none of the error logs are written. The only thing that gets written to this file is the system messages when mysql is restarted.

The one thing I see different with `error.log` is that the owner of this file is `mysql:mysql`. I tried changing the owner of this file to `mysql:adm`, but still, no error logs are being written.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe there is nothing to report, what is really strange, but cam happen

Comment: @nbk Yeah, I forgot to mention that I deliberately tried some failed login attempts to trigger writing an error and it never did.

Comment: error log are written when mysql runs into an error internally, low memory joint ables to small etc.

Comment: just restart your (mysql) server. the last line in the error log should be something like: `2021-11-19T17:01:38.124860Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'`  (of course with the current time, and the version from MySQL that you installed)

Comment: BTW, I was just installin MySQL8.0.27 on Ubuntu20.04, and initially the owner on `error.log` was `mysql:adm`, but after i removed that file, and restarted MySQL, that file was owned by `mysql:mysql`.